# Instagram "posted for first time in a while" notification

Tags: mobile, push-notification, instagram, instagram-api

Does anyone know how Instagram determines whether or not to send a push notification saying "_______ has posted for the first time in a while". Is it based purely on time, or is it different based on how often the user posts? If it's based on the individual person, what is the algorithm they use to determine whether a notification should be sent?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how often you post before. If you post every day, but then only post a week later, the notification may appear. 
In general, it could be some range from 1 to 3 weeks to multiple months.